# jQuery Ajax Promise: Throw Custom Exception and have it caught in outer fail()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Suppose I have a function that returns a `promise`. The returned promise is examined by outer functions to decide how to handle the `.fail()` condition.

```
function refreshTimeline() {
    var promise = ajaxMethod1()
                  .then (function (data) {
                      return ajaxMethod2()
                  }) 
                  .then(function(json) {
                      //...
                  });
    return promise;
}

function outerFunction() {
     refreshTimeline
     .then(function() {
          //...
     })
     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // This will handle any errors in the chain *including* the refreshTimeline        
     });    
}
```

My issue is I need to throw a **custom business exception** in refreshTimeline() which should be caught by the outer function just as it would any regular Ajax error. The goal is to have outerFunction's `fail()` get this exception, and maybe handle it in a special way (maybe it needs to recognize it).

But the following doesn't work:

```
  function refreshTimeline() {
        var promise = ajaxMethod1()
                      .then (function (data) {
                          return ajaxMethod2()
                      }) 
                      .then(function(json) {
                          if (someBusinessCondition(json) {
                               // throw custom exception
                               throw "MyException"; //JS gives "Uncaught" msg
                          }
                      });
        return promise;
    }
```

So, I don't want to handle this business error myself in `refreshTimeline()` (because it's not the job of this utility function -- it just forwards errors downstream) and I want to propagate it down to outer error handlers which would treat is a regular `.fail()`. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest returning a different promise rather than the one created by your ajaxMethod1.  If you had a secondary promise, you could resolve it in the good case, and in the bad case you could resolve it with extra information identifying your "exception" that the fail methods placed on it could reference.  Rather than doing a true throwable.

Comment: @Taplar I think the biggest problem is that Gene is using a jQuery version that has Deferred that behaves badly. If you want to use jQuery deferred instead of a (properly polyfilled) promise then use version 3. If your code throws for any reason in a resolve handler you will get uncaught exception instead of rejected promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of throwing an Exception, return a rejected deferred/promise instance with your string/Exception/whatever object as the argument.

```
function refreshTimeline() {
    var promise = ajaxMethod1()
        .then (function (data) {
            return ajaxMethod2();
        }) 
        .then(function(json) {
            if (someBusinessCondition(json) {
                // return your error as a rejected (failed) promise
                return $.Deferred().reject("MyException");
            }
        });
    return promise;
}
```

This will call your outer `.fail()` with `"MyException"` as the value of the first parameter (which you named `jqXHR`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems jQuery 3 was released on [Jun 2016](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), maybe it is time to use it since it has deferred that actually behaves like promises.

```js
jQuery.Deferred().resolve(22)
.then(
  result=>{
    console.log("got result:",result);
    throw("rejecting");
  }
).catch(
  err=>console.warn("got the error:",err)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Or you can use (a properly polyfilled) Promise with old jQuery:

```js
Promise.resolve(22)//starting an actual promise chain (not badly behaving deferred)
.then(
  //returning the defected deferred does not affect promise chain
  //  promise will handle it as a promise like and then returns an actual promise
  result=>jQuery.Deferred().resolve(result)
)
.then(
  result=>{
    console.log("got result:",result);
    throw("whatever reason your code throws"); 
  }
)
.catch(
  err=>console.warn("error caught:",err)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```